# AngularJS: if item in loop equals current location then print specific class

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have below code:

```
<ul ng-init="urls = ['/home', '/news', '/contactUs']">
<li ng-repeat="url in urls>
<a class="current-page" href="{{url}}">
{{url}}
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

For each `<a>` tag in the `ng-repeat` loop, if `{{url}}` is qual to `window.location.href.split('?')[0]` then I wants to print the current-page class for that `<a>` tag. Else, it should not be shown.
In simple words I wants something like this: `{{url || if(url == window.location.href.split('?')[0])}}`

Is it possible with AngularJS ? Then how?

Comment: Be aware that `window.location.href` will also include scheme ("http" or "https") in addition to host ("example.com") and pathname ("/home").

Comment: @Adriani6 directives are not applicable here because here we wants to hide a class only and not the entire a element.

Comment: @NodeDev I have edited and suggested a more specific title, feel free to roll back or further update the title if it isn't what you're trying to ask. (The previous one was a bit too abstract to see what's being asked, I think.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `['example.com/home', 'example.com/news', 'example.com/contactUs']` then I suggest this:

```
<a ng-class="{ 'current-page': (window.location.host + window.location.pathname).indexOf(url) >= 0 }">{{url}}</a>
```

But if you have `['/home', '/news', '/contactUs']` then this is enough:

```
<a ng-class="{ 'current-page': window.location.pathname.indexOf(url) >= 0 }">{{url}}</a>
```

Given your example `urls` I think this is better because `href` would include the scheme ('https' for example) as well so no match would pop up.

You could of course replace `indexOf(...)` with an exact match, if that's more appropriate.

It uses the fact that `ng-class` can take in a map from potential classes (`'current-page'`) to expressions that are coerced to a boolean value after evaluation (e.g. the `indexOf(...)` expression). See [these docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

Comment: Can you please edit the answer for the updated array in question?

Comment: @NodeDev Updated my answer following your updated question.

Comment: Great! I appreciate your help